# Unable to Check Out Bundles for TextMate using SVN

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I was following the instructions on this page to check out all bundles for TextMate using SVN:

http://wiki.macromates.com/Main/SubversionCheckout

When I issued this command:

svn co http://svn.textmate.org/trunk ./

Encountered the following error message:

svn: Can't create directory '.svn': Permission denied

What would be the appropriate credentials as they weren't specified on the wiki page?

Would appreciate it if someone could offer me some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message your are getting is caused on your local machine. it appears you do not have write access to the directory you are in. check and correct the permissions/try your homedirectory/as another user, then issue the svn command again.

Comment: You were right! I issued a chmod +x on the ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles/ dir and everything worked! Thank you!